# If $f$ is differentiable on a closed bounded interval, is $f$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

I am working on this problem:

I want to prove that when $f$ is differentiable on a closed interval $[x_1,x_2]$, where $x_2>x_1$, $f$ is bounded.

At first I was thinking that I could prove (by contradiction) that $f$ had to be bounded because $\infty$ cannot be on a closed interval. And since $f$ is on a closed interval, it can't be unbounded. But I think we're supposed to use the mean value theorem.

So, I know that $f$ is bounded on $I$ when there exists a constant K such that $|f(x)|\leq K$ for all $x \epsilon I$. Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous. Vi can thus use the mean value theorem. We manipulte the formula a bit and get:
$f'(c)(x_2-x_1)=f(x_2)-f(x_1)$, since $f$ is bounded at $|f(x)|\leq K$, 
$|f'(c)||x_2-x_1|=|f(x_2)-f(x_1)|$

Now, I'm trying to get to a point where I can prove that $f\leq K$, probably using the triangle inequality? Also that I could solve the MVT-expression for $f(x)$ when the $|MVT|\leq K$? Am I on to something?

Comment: A continuous function on a closed interval is bounded. See theorem 5 in http://www2.kau.se/yourshes/AB2_15.pdf

Comment: Ah, I actually had that .pdf on my computer.. Thank you for pointing it out. Altough the proof does not use MVT. Isn't it possible to prove it with MVT?

Comment: There's no reason to invoke theorems involving differentiability here. Just use continuity.

Comment: Got it. So what if the interval was open? $I=(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: If the interval is open you can't say the function is bounded. Consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a function $f$ defined and continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ is bounded is ultimately a consequence of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. BWT states that any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

You could use BWT indirectly to prove that $f$ is bounded.  Assume that $f$ is unbounded.  This implies that for any positive integer $n$ there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x_n)| > n$ -- leading eventually to a contradiction.

On the other hand, you can use another consequence of BWT, that the closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ is compact, implying that any open cover has a finite subcover.  In this way you can salvage your proof.  You have shown that for any point $x \in [a,b]$ there exists an interval $I_x = (x - \delta_x,x + \delta_x)$ where $f$ is locally bounded, i.e. $|f(y)| < M_x$ for all $y \in I_x$.

Since $[a,b] \subset \cup_{x \in [a,b]}I_x$, then compactness implies there are a finite number of points $x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $[a,b] \subset \cup_{k=1}^nI_{x_k}.$ Take $M = \max(M_{x_1}, M_{x_2}, \ldots, M_{x_n}).$  For any $x \in [a,b]$ there exists $1 \leqslant j \leqslant n$ such that $x \in I_{x_j}$and $|f(x)| < M_{x_j} < M$.

Answer (score 0):

*edited*

Ok so I tired to combine [theorem 1 and 5 and collary 1.](http://www2.kau.se/yourshes/AB2_15.pdf)

$f(x)$ is differentiable on $[x_1,x_2]$, thus it is also continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$. Given that $f(x)$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, which leads to $f(x)$ being bounded on the neighbourhood $x_0$ on $[x_1,x_2]$. Furthermore, if $f$ is bounded on $x_0$, $f$ itself is bounded on $[x_1,x_2]$. Which was to be proven. $\blacksquare$

Comment: No, it doesn't work. "Bounded at a point" doesn't mean anything. If you mean "$f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $x_0$", then that's true, but just because for each point, a function is bounded in some neighborhood of that point, that doesn't mean the function if bounded. For example, given any $x_0$, for small enough $\delta$, the function $1/x$ is bounded on $[x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$. But it's not bounded.

Comment: Hm I thought so.. So I can take an arbitrary bounded $x_0$ (neighborhood) on $[x_1,x_2]$, which implies that $f$ itself is bounded on $[x_1,x_2]$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "Take an arbitrary bounded neighbourhood", and then do what with it?

Comment: Well, [theorem 1](http://www2.kau.se/yourshes/AB2_15.pdf) states that if $x_0$ is bounded on the interval, then $f$ is bounded on that same interval, right? I just tought they ment $x_0$ as a singel point, but as you pointed out, it has to be a neighbourhood. So maybe not an arbitrary $x_0$, but a specific neighbourhood $x_0$ which is bounded on all points on $x_0$.

Comment: Okay, yes, if $f$ is bounded at each point (meaning there exists a neighborhood of each point on which $f$ is bounded), then $f$ is bounded on the whole interval, *if the interval is closed and bounded*. So in your case of an interval $[x_1, x_2]$, the argument works. But if you're going to be using theorems from that PDF, you may as well just use Theorem 5, which states exactly what you're trying to prove!

Comment: OK great. Yes I saw, but it refers to T.1 and lemma 1, so I figured I had to expand on it. Since I can't just say, see T.1 from a random pdf I found online lol.

Comment: No, but the theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval is bounded is well known and you can probably quote that without proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a compact space and let $T$ be any space . If $f:S\to T$ is continuous then the image $f''S=\{f(x):s\in S\}$ is a compact subspace of $T.$ In other words, the continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Proof:

Let $G$ be an open family in $T$ with $\cup G\supset f''S.$  Then $J=\{f^{-1}H:H\in G\}$ is an open family in $S$ because $f$ is continuous.  Obviously $\cup J=S,$ and so we can take a finite $J^*\subset J$ with $\cup J^*=S.$

For each $j\in J^*$ take $\psi(j)\in H$ satisfying  $f^{-1}\psi (j)=j.$ Then $\{\psi (j):j\in J^*\}$ is a finite subset of G, and is a cover of  $f''S.$ QED.

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable then  $f$ is continuous. And $[a,b]$ is compact. So $f''[a,b]$ is compact, hence it is bounded.

The notation $f''A=\{f(a):a\in A\}$ when $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f,$ is read "$f$ double-prime $A$".